# Сменить URL для ресурса, если локально не найден

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

Подскажите правило, чтобы в случае 404 ошибки (к примеру, загрузки отсутствующей картинки) изменять запрос на другой хост.

Нужно для того, что бы в существующем проекте не изменять *URL* всех недостающих ресурсов, а просто брать их с удаленного сервера.

Comment: А интересно, такое не работает: `ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/%{REQUEST_URI}`

Comment: @splash58 а такое работает ) Но, оказалось еще есть ссылки на удаленные хосты, где опять же генериться 404 ошибка

Comment: тогда пишите обработчик. кто-то же должен понять, отправлять на другой сайт или показывать ошибку.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
# проверка, что файл к которому обратились не существует на сервере
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# уточняем к каким типам файлов будет применена переадресация
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$
# редирект на другой сайт
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newHost.ru/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404/
ErrorDocument 500 http://example.com/500/
```

если нужно обработать ошибку можно так

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404/
ErrorDocument 500 http://example.com/500/
# или прямо на скрипт обработки:
# ErrorDocument 404 /pages/errors/error_redirect.php
# ErrorDocument 500 /pages/errors/error_redirect.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/errors/404.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/500/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/errors/500.php [L]

# или так в одной строке:
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$ [OR]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/500/$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/errors/error_redirect.php [L]
```

Comment: я не совсем разбираюсь в этом синтаксисе, но должно быть так:
1) Отправлен запрос: http://site/files/image.png
2) Если 404, то обращаемся к http://{newHost}/files/image.png

Comment: проверьте у себя и скажите полусилось или нет